# In Fullmetal Alchemist, what does a State Alchemist's pocket watch do?

Tags: fullmetal-alchemist-series

In Fullmetal Alchemist, it is stated a number of times that a state alchemist's pocket watch increases their power, but there doesn't seem to be a clear mechanism for that. How does that work, and what does increasing the power of an alchemist mean?

Comment: Besides increasing the power of a state alchemist, it is also proof they are one.

Comment: If it was a power amplifier, an easy mechanism would be for red stones to be stashed in the watch's body.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As stated in [this wiki](http://fma.wikia.com/wiki/State_Alchemist),

> ...each State Alchemist is given a silver pocketwatch to
>   hold as identification. This watch is engraved with the symbol of the
>   State Alchemist program - the Amestrian Dragon circumscribed in a
>   hexagram (though both anime series alter the hexagram to a nondescript
>   polygram, presumably so as not to invoke Judaism). Although **the manga
>   does not describe the pocketwatch as anything more than official proof
>   that the carrier is a State Alchemist**, **the 2003 anime suggests that
>   each pocketwatch is an alchemical amplifier**. The 2003 anime also
>   depicts the watch's silver chain as extendable, as in the instance
>   when the Strong Arm Alchemist, Major Alex Louis Armstrong uses it to
>   tie up a target.

So, according to the 2003 anime, the watch amplifies the alchemist's powers. However, both manga and *FMA:Brotherhood* shows that the watch is simply a form of identification, much like a police badge.

Also note that in the anime the watch is the indicator which people use to recognize Edward as a State Alchemist. I believe that unless the State Alchemist himself tells you who he is, the presence of the watch is the only other way to know it (they also get a certificate, but I doubt they carry it around).

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, but what I'm more wondering is if it is ever explained what exactly an alchemical amplifier would do (the mechanics of it).

Answer (score 8):

They never explained it because it is a development of the first anime adaptation that was never expounded upon. The watches were merely forms of identification as state alchemists in Brotherhood, which follows the manga more closely.

Answer (score 3):

They actually showed this in one episode when Ed got his watched repaired, that it contained red rocks in the back of it and that was how they amplified their alchemic powers.

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga SE! Do you know what episode this was in, or have a screenshot of it? This might help your answer stand on its own a little better.

Comment: I remember seeing that episode in the 2003 anime. The anime based closely on the manga did not have any special powers associated with the watch, other than it was a badge of office.

Answer (score 0):

The Silver Pocketwatches amplify the State Alchemist's power, but besides that, the only thing they really do is prove that you're a State Alchemist, and perhaps to tell the time.

Answer (score 0):

They tell time but mainly symbolize being a state alchemist and part of the country's government and army if necessary.